# Response hangs probably because of invalid content length using netty

Tags: java, json, netty, content-length

I have created a small HttpServer for my application. It is used for serving a sort of API and some json repsponses. All o my responses tested so far work great except for one. I use GSON for the json part. Part of my code that is handling the response creation is the following

```
JsonObject jsonResult = new JsonObject();
JsonArray jsonResultItem = new JsonArray();
for (Entry<Integer, TestcaseStatusReport> item : testcaseStatuses.entrySet()){
    JsonObject tempJson = new JsonObject();
    tempJson.addProperty("id", item.getKey());
    tempJson.addProperty("status", item.getValue().getStatus().toString());
    jsonResultItem.add(tempJson);

}

jsonResult.add("result", jsonResultItem);
return jsonResult;
```

the response is then created using this jsonResult

```
private static FullHttpResponse createResponse(JsonObject jsonResponse) {
    ByteBuf buffer = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(jsonResponse.toString(),
            CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
    FullHttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(
                                                            HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1,
                                                            HttpResponseStatus.OK,
                                                            buffer);
    HttpHeaders.setContentLength(response, buffer.readableBytes());
    response.headers().set(HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_TYPE,
            "application/json");

    return response;
}
```

I pass the jsonResult object from above as parameter. In debug mode I saw that the json created was the following

```
{"result":[{"id":2,"status":"Starting"}]}
```

and the responses content length is 41 which agrees. But still it hangs. I use the same function (createResponse) for other api calls and pass other jsonResponse parameters and works fine. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please delete or leave....I had forgotten to write the response to the context...:)...My bad...

Comment: Thanks for posting how you were able to progress :) Please leave the question as others may have similar issues in the future and find this helpful.